# Assets file obj\project.assets.json doesn't have a target - VS2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Using Visual Studio 2017, AspNetCore 1.1.2

All of a sudden I am getting following error when I am trying to publish (Release build) any project in the solution:

> Assets file 'C:\example\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2/win7-x86'. Ensure that restore has run
>   and that you have included 'net452' in the TargetFrameworks for your
>   project. You may also need to include 'win7-x86' in your project's
>   RuntimeIdentifiers.

Have checked in the `project.assets.json` files, I have:

```
"targets": {
  ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2": {
```

and

```
"runtimes": {
  "win7-x86": {
    "#import": []
  }
```

In the *.csproj files I have:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
      <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Have made no changes to config in the projects. Only thing is that I have updated VS2017 to latest version today, 15.6.3. Could this cause issue?

Comment: Does deletion of "C:\example\ob" folder and rebuild help?

Comment: No sorry same issue.

Comment: Please clarify: .NET Framework and .NET Core are two different things. It doesn't appear that you're using .NET Core at all here.

Comment: take a look: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1321

Comment: Just in case someone finds this after running into the same problem as me: one of the issues you can run into is a mismatch between .NET Standard and .NET Core when you're doing multi-targeting. You can't have a library target .NET Standard and then use `dotnet build -f netcoreapp2.1` despite the code being technically compatible. You either need to use `-f netstandard2.0` and add that to your assets file as a target, or switch to targeting .NET Core 2.1.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-NETSDK1005:-Assets-file-projecta/1248649?preview=true

Answer (score 163, accepted):

According to the Microsoft blog (which, bizarrely, my account doesn't have permissions to post in), this *isn't* a bug, and is entirely caused by ReSharper.  If you disable this, the problem goes away.

Errr, one problem: I'm getting this error, and I don't have ReSharper.

After a *lot* of hunting around, I found the reason I was getting the error on my .NET Core project which had been upgraded from 1.0 to 2.1.

When running my project in Debug or Release mode, everything worked fine, but when I tried to publish to Azure, I got that error:

> Assets file '(mikesproject)\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp2.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.

Although I had updated the version of .NET Core to 2.1 in Project\Properties and upgraded the various nuget packages, there was one place which hadn't picked up this change... the  Publish Profile file.

I needed to go into the `Properties\PublishProfiles` folder in my solution, open up the `.pubxml` file relating to the way I was publishing to Azure, and change this setting from `netcoreapp2.0` to `netcoreapp2.1`:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    . . . 
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    . . . 
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Ridiculous, hey?

I do wish Microsoft error messages gave some clue as to the source of problems like this.

Comment: Removed and created a new Publish Profile and then it worked!

Comment: I'm running into the same thing now. I have a simple class library project targeting both net47 and net6.0. Resharper disabled and no .pubxml file. I'm at a loss on why this is happening. (BTW, running "dotnet build" in "development powershell" works and creates a good project.assets.json file. =/

Answer (score 133):

Restarting Visual Studio solved the error for me.

Comment: Updated an open solution from github which included new framework targets, this answer fixed the problem when nothing else did.

Comment: This solved my issue in VS 16.8.2 with <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>

Comment: I upgraded a handful of .NET standard 2.0 libraries in a solution to 2.1, everything was normal at first until I did some stashing and changed branches; then I was met with this when trying to run tests. Restarting VS cleared the issue...

Comment: Still applicable in VS2022 and .NET 7.0.

Comment: I don't know why I even think about searching a solution to my problems before restarting everything. +1 from me.

Answer (score 57):

Right click on the project file, and click unload.  Then right click on the project and reload.

Comment: This worked for me after I also "Rebuilt" the offending project

Comment: this worked in VS2022

Answer (score 44):

Had this error in similar situation. This has helped me: [Link](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1321#issuecomment-323606946)

This is my property group in *.csproj file of my .net core 3.0 project:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>  <----- SOLVES IT. Mandatory Line
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Hint: If you face new/other issues by this change (especially when working with EF Core), just use the plural form instead: `<RuntimeIdentifiers>`.

Answer (score 28):

**Migrating from nuget 5.4 to nuget 5.8** solve the problem on my devops build server

Comment: kayleeFrye_onDeck's answer is the better answer here, because it gives a pointer to an article that explains _why_ the upgrade is the thing to do.

Comment: How to migrate nuget version?

Comment: How did you find out it's required. What would be the root cause @k4str042

Answer (score 13):

Delete the publish profile you created and create a new one. The wizard will put in the correct targetframe work for you and publish again. It should solve the problem.

Comment: This is absolutely the "best" answer for most circumstances.

Answer (score 7):

If your build script starts with a `dotnet restore` and ends with a `dotnet publish --no-restore`, you must make sure that they both include the same `--runtime` parameter.

Comment: This was actually my problem on GitHub Actions

Answer (score 5):

For me it was the happening because I had migrated my project from `.net5.0` to `.net6.0` and the problem was caused when I was publishing the project while debugging worked fine.

Checking the publishing profile showed that it had a configuration for `.net5.0` in it:

[image: .net5.0 publishing profile]

Changing the existing `.net core` version with the desired one resolved the issue:

---

[image: Change .net5.0 to .net6.0]

---

Or you can directly change it by going into the publishing profile `.pubxml` file under `Properties > PublishingProfiles` directory.

[image: .pubxml]

Comment: Same for me.  Upvoting.

Comment: This happened for me after upgrading from .NET 6 to 7.  I restarted Visual Studio per a popular answer, but I bet I didn't need to.  I saw the dropdown saying "6" the next time I went to Publish.   Changed it to 7 and success.

Answer (score 4):

Restarting Visual Studio or unloading/reloading the project didn't work for me, but deleting the "obj" folder and then rebuilding seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when upgrading a web project from netcoreapp3.1 to net5.0.

One of the answers here pointed me in the right direction:

*The publish profile still had netcoreapp3.1 as target framework.* Edited the publish profile and changed target framework to net5.0 and it worked.

(Visual Studio 16.8)

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem ended up being that one of my NuGet feeds was down, so a package was not getting updated properly. It wasn't until I ran a NuGet package restore directly on the solution that I saw any error messages related to my NuGet feed being down.

Answer (score 3):

You should try all the other solutions here first. Failing that you can try what eventually unblocked me when none of these did. I ran into this problem when porting a Jenkins build to an Azure DevOps pipeline on a pool of agents. It took about 60 builds before I tried every other possibility. I found out that needed to do two things:

1. Ensure the tooling was consistent for this specific project
2. Use a nuget restore friendly with the version of MSBuild used after [finding out that mattered](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/error-NETSDK1005:-Assets-file-projecta/1248649?preview=true) yet I couldn't use the proposed workaround for just updated nuget tooling.

The versions I needed to use are likely different than yours.

1:

```
call choco install windows-adk-all --version=10.0.15063.0 --force

call choco install windows-sdk-10.1 --version=10.1.15063.468 --force
```

2:

```
call MSBuild -t:restore Solution.sln

call MSBuild Solution.sln /t:rebuild;pack /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

Comment: Sadly, the hyperlink here is the explanation that all of the other "upgrade XYZ" answers lacked.

Answer (score 3):

Running `dotnet restore --packages .nuget` in the project directory fixed the issues for me.

Answer (score 2):

To me, the error was caused because of an existing *global.json* file in the solution level folder, pointing to a different .NET version.
Removing that file (or changing its SDK version) resolved the problem

Comment: We added a file 'global.json' and specified version as
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.1.509",
    "rollForward": "latestFeature"
  }
}

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading NuGet version from 5.5.1 to 5.8.0 fixed the issue.

Comment: How did you find out it's required. What would be the root cause @ak_01

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue, when I installed a new sdk version.

Exception was:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error NETSDK1005
Assets file '.. \RazorPages\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 
'netcoreapp3.1'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp3.1' 
in the TargetFrameworks for your project. RazorPages 
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk
\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    241
```

Solution was to select again the target version of the project.

1. right click on  solution
2. Properties\Application Tab
3. Change Target framework version  to something different and change it back.

Comment: The error happened to me because I mistakenly compiled the solution in an old VS version, which restored odd dependencies. This answer solved the problem to me.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague ran into this after upgrading an application from dotnet core 1.1 to dotnet core 2.1. He properly updated all the targetFramework references within the various csproj files, and had no issues on his local development machine. However, we run Azure DevOps Server and build agents on-premises, so the build agent was reporting this error after a pull request build was executed.

The `dotnet clean` task was throwing an error because of the new targeted framework. `dotnet clean` uses the same targets as build, publish, etc, so after a change in target frameworks the `dotnet restore` *must* happen before the `dotnet clean` to update the dependent files. In hindsight this makes sense because you want to restore dependencies to the proper target framework before you do any building or deploying.

This may only affect projects with upgraded target frameworks but I have not tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Receiving similar error for 'netcoreapp3.1' when building using command line. It turned out to be an MsBuild switch that caused the issue. Specifically speaking:

```
/p:TargetFramework="netcoreapp3.1"
```

Removed the switch and the error was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the `NETSDK1047` when playing around with Docker in a brand new dotnet project created using `dotnet new worker` and the docker file from [dotnet-docker samples](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/3739ebf9f8fa2cc85eb3b73bc00fca467672771f/samples/dotnetapp/Dockerfile.alpine-x64-slim).

```
❯ docker build -t dockertest .

output elided...

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.300/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): error NETSDK1047: Assets file '/source/obj/project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0/linux-musl-x64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'linux-musl-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers. [/source/dockertest.csproj]
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish -c release -o /app -r linux-musl-x64 --self-contained true --no-restore /p:PublishTrimmed=true /p:PublishReadyToRun=true /p:PublishSingleFile=true' returned a non-zero code: 1
dockertest on  main [✘] via .NET v6.0.202  net6.0
❯
```

The issue was because I forgot to add a `.dockerignore` [file](https://github.com/willbush/dockertest/blob/08ef0c3cd7d984af20902245d9573fdf3601223b/.dockerignore) ignoring the `bin` and `obj` directories.

I only realized why because I tried different Dockerfiles from the `dotnet-docker` repo and got a [different error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1064) which has this same resolution. I'll try to make a PR to the docs of `NETSDK1047` to add this resolution. edit: link to PR https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/29530

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded from netstandard to net6.0, when publishing had to change TargetFramework to net6.0
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1005

> When the .NET SDK issues error NETSDK1005 or NETSDK1047, the project's
> assets file is missing information on one of your target frameworks.
> NuGet writes a file named project.assets.json in the obj folder, and
> the .NET SDK uses it to get information about packages to pass into
> the compiler.

First ensure that a nuget restore for your project works correctly using `dotnet restore`. Resolve any issues first, then try rebuilding your project (you may need to delete the `obj` folder first).

Answer (score 0):

In my case updating visual studio 2019 to the latest version, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, if you have `TargetFrameworks` and `TargetFramework` together in the csrpoj file, remove `TargetFramework` will solve the problem.

edit it from:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net461;</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework><!--remove this line-->
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

to

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net461;</TargetFrameworks>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience if you have dependencies in your solution built using "ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject"
then in this case dotnet build goes nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, for me it was that I had a space before my `TargetFramework`

```
<TargetFramework> net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

Answer (score 0):

On my end I had this issue with net6.0 at build time, even before trying to publish. Even if everything was pointing to csproj and it had all the right TargetFramework, the issue was that our repo had a Nuget.Config at it's root and it included a configuration for a local disk Nuget Repo of another programmer. I disabled the Nuget.Config file and I was able to build the project. It was probably unable to restore the Nuget Packages but the error message was misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit target framework in profile to new dot net version. It can resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: For my problem I didn't need to delete profile as on of answer was said. Editing just target framework need to solve my proble. So I posted my answer if ot can help.

Comment: Yes, but has that answer not been given before? Indeed, [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52592153/3025856) suggests just that, as does [@antca230's answer based on .NET 5+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72660258/3025856). Please be sure to read existing answers before contributing your own. Once you have enough reputation, you can then upvote existing answers that you find useful or correct and want to help validate. In the meanwhile, kindly remove this answer since it is effectively a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

clean cache and restart VS then it worked for me.